# Does calling the constructor of an empty class actually use any memory?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, micro-optimization

Suppose I have a class like

```
class Empty{
    Empty(int a){ cout << a; }
}
```

And then I invoke it using

```
int main(){
    Empty(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Will this cause any memory to be allocated on the stack for the creation of an "Empty" object? Obviously, the arguments need to be pushed onto the stack, but I don't want to incur any extra overhead. Basically I am using the constructor as a static member.

The reason I want to do this is because of templates. The actual code looks like

```
template <int which>
class FuncName{
    template <class T>
    FuncName(const T &value){
        if(which == 1){
            // specific behavior
        }else if(which == 2){
            // other specific behavior
        }
    }
};
```

which allows me to write something like

```
int main(){
    int a = 1;
    FuncName<1>(a);
}
```

so that I get to specialize one template parameter, while not having to specify the type of `T`. Also, I am hoping the compiler will optimize the other branches away inside the constructor. If anyone knows if this is true or how to check, that would be greatly appreciated. I assumed also that throwing templates into the situation does not change the "empty class" problem from above, is that right?

Comment: The question is why do you care. It is the job of the compiler to care and generate the best code. You should be concentrating on writting the most expressive code.

Comment: PS. There is no requirement for the argument to be pushed on the stack. The C++ ABI is delibrately not defined so that compilers have the opertunity to use register to pass parameters if that makes the code more effecient

Comment: I care because I want the highest performance I can get; I really hate the attitude that code should be elegant and not worry about these things. Sometimes, these things matter (I do high performance computing).

Comment: PPS. With template specialization there is no need for an if in the above template.

Comment: @Victor: Then there are better things to worry about then usage of stack object (whcih has no cost) in comparison to the branch operation in your template which may generate a processor stall. The reason code should be elegant is not that we like pritty code, but rather that elegant code is generally more optimizable by the compiler. If you really care about performance then you should worry about the things that matter not the micro optimizations. I really hate is the attitute that writting macro optimizations is good because I am real programmer, the real optimizer writes the compiler (me).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quoting Stroustrup:

Why is the size of an empty class not zero?
To ensure that the addresses of two different objects will be different. For the same reason, "new" always returns pointers to distinct objects. Consider:

```
class Empty { };

void f()
{
    Empty a, b;
    if (&a == &b) cout << "impossible: report error to compiler supplier";

    Empty* p1 = new Empty;
    Empty* p2 = new Empty;
    if (p1 == p2) cout << "impossible: report error to compiler supplier";
}
```

There is an interesting rule that says that an empty base class need not be represented by a separate byte:

```
struct X : Empty {
    int a;
    // ...
};

void f(X* p)
{
    void* p1 = p;
    void* p2 = &p->a;
    if (p1 == p2) cout << "nice: good optimizer";
}
```

This optimization is safe and can be most useful. It allows a programmer to use empty classes to represent very simple concepts without overhead. Some current compilers provide this "empty base class optimization".

Comment: But what if the object created is never referenced at all? Is the compiler allowed to either reserve no stack space for it, or immediately clean it up even though it didn't go out of scope?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that a compiler will eliminate the reserved memory altogether if it isn't used or referenced. It's a pretty simple optimization. Depending on the compiler, of course.

Comment: As long as the behvior is not altered then the compiler is free to eliminate the whole concept of the object under the hood and the whole thing may be inlined into the code and all values stored in registers.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question

Answer (score 2):

It might, it might, not, depending on circumstances. If you say:

```
Empty e;
Empty * ep = & e;
```

then obviously things have to be allocated.

Comment: Does the compiler necessarily have to emit code _allocate_ something in order to give it an address though? Is there are reason why &e can't be an address that is neither heap nor stack, and where there is no actual object?

Comment: @Autopulated: I believe so, see Richard Pennington's comment. The more interesting question is if you never ask for its address; then does it still have to have one? (A very zen-like question)

Comment: If you take the address of e, and then do something with that address (which my example code doesn't) then e must be instantiated  -   i.e. allocated.

Comment: For instance, if you compare pointers to two different objects of type Empty, then they have to be non-equal. So the compiler must then arrange to give them different addresses. Whether they're "actually on the stack" or not is beyond the scope of the language, but clearly in practice the compiler has to allocate addresses to them. Even if it were uncommitted space, do we really think that 1 byte of uncommitted address space is any cheaper to allocate than 1 byte of stack? If you never take the address, the compiler knows you'll never use it, and some compilers sometimes do elide the object.

Answer (score 2):

Try it and see. Many compilers will eliminate such temporary objects when asked to optimise their output.

If the disassembly is too complex, then create two functions with different numbers of such objects and see if there is any difference in the stack locations of objects surrounding them, something like:

```
void empty1 ( int x )
{
    using namespace std;

    int a;
    Empty e1 ( x );
    int b;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "empty1" << endl;
    cout << hex << int ( &x ) << " " << dec << ( &x - &a ) << endl;
    cout << hex << int ( &a ) << " " << dec << ( &a - &b ) << endl;
}
```

and then try running that compared with an `empty8` function with eight Empties created. With g++ on x86, if you do take the address of any of the empties you get a location between x and a on the stack, hence including x in the output. You can't assume that the storage for objects will end up in the same order as they are declared in the source code.

Comment: How? I'm looking at the g++ assembly listing for a simple example and it's very hard to follow. I'm using `g++ -c -g -O2 -Wa,-ahl=file.s file.cpp`

Comment: You might get on better compiling to an executable (with debug info), then use `objdump -dS`, and search for the source lines you're interested in. Since you have optimisation on, remember that the same source line is liable to appear in multiple places in the disassembly.